# bootstrap-select -clone with event and regenerate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, clone, bootstrap-select

Hello i try to duplicate html code with a bootstrap-select, when i clone it i must destroy html of bootstrap-select for regenerate plugin code but i have a problem, bootstrap-select doesn't generate new dropdown.
Initially all cloned event was referenced to first dropdown, if i change second dropdown data change on the first, than i remove element of second dropdown and i try to regenerate it.

i create my problem on codepen, is here: http://codepen.io/valix85/pen/dogrRX
can you help me to fix this problem? thank you

code interessed:

```
var ob2 = obTMP.clone(true).insertAfter($(".box-variants").last());
ob2.css("background", "#a9c");

ob2.find(".bootstrap-select").remove();
ob2.find("select.selectprodmaterials").removeClass("bs-select-hidden");
ob2.find("select.selectprodvariants").removeClass("bs-select-hidden");

var ob2m = ob2.find("select.selectprodmaterials");
var ob2v = ob2.find("select.selectprodvariants").css("background", "yellow");
ob2.find("select.selectprodmaterials").css("background", "pink");

ob2m.selectpicker();
ob2v.selectpicker();
```

Comment: Please edit the relevant code into the question itself. It's good that you have linked to it, but you should also include it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: this is a code to check, i think problem is here not in clone process (but check it soo pls)